# How do I find the degree of the splitting field?

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field

I'm trying to find the degree of the splitting field of the polynomial
$p(x) = x^{8}+5x^{4}-14$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Here are my steps:
Factoring p(x), we have $p(x) = (x^{4}-2)(x^{4}+7)$.
Setting p(x) equal to $0$, $x=\pm\sqrt[4]{2}, \pm\sqrt[4]{-7}$.
Letting $\zeta_{4}^{k} = e^{2ki\pi/4}, x=\pm\sqrt[4]{2}, \pm\sqrt[4]{-7}, \zeta_{4}(\pm\sqrt[4]{2}), \zeta_{4}(\pm\sqrt[4]{-7}), \zeta_{4}^{3}(\pm\sqrt[4]{2}), \zeta_{4}^{3}(\pm\sqrt[4]{-7})$.
Then our splitting field of $p(x)$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, \sqrt[4]{-7}, \zeta_{4}, \zeta_{4}^{3})$. Does this mean that the degree of the splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ is equal to $4+4+2+2=12$? This doesn't seem right.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez For $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, \sqrt[4]{-7})$, the degrees are 4. I was told that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{a}, \sqrt[m]{b}): \mathbb{Q}] = n+m$. So $4+4=8.$ Also, $[\mathbb{Q}(i, i^{3}):\mathbb{Q}] = 2+2 = 4$ I think.

Comment: Ok I kinda thought so but wasn’t sure. So is the degree 10?

Comment: Whoever told you to **add** degrees of simple extensions is very confused. Have you seen the tower law?

Comment: No, I have not seen the tower law.

Comment: [Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension#The_multiplicativity_formula_for_degrees).

Comment: For example the field $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5)$ is a degree eight extension, $8=2\cdot2\cdot2$. One basis consists of $1,\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt6,\sqrt5,\sqrt{10},\sqrt{15},\sqrt{30}$.